# How do you add a current class to a li with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
 <ul>
    <li class="tree">
    <span><a class="collapse" href="#">Collapse</a></span>
    </li>
    <li class="tree">
<span><a class="expand" href="#">Expand</a></span>
</li>
    </ul>
```

How can I add a class on the li to current when you click on the expand link and then take off the current when I click on the collapse in jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.collapse').click(function(e){

    $(this).closest('li').removeClass('current');

});

$('.expand').click(function(e){

    $(this).closest('li').addClass('current');

});
```

if you need to stop the anchor going to the link, use:

```
e.preventDefault()
```

before the class add/removal.

Answer (score 0):

adding class

```
$(".expand").click(function(){ 
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('current'); 
});
```

removing class

```
$(".collapse").click(function(){ 
    $(this).closest('li').removeClass('current'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".expand").click( function() {

   $(this).closest('li').addClass('current');

});


$(".collapse").click( function() {

   $(this).closest('li').removeClass('current');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

@rob waminal
More information can be found, http://api.jquery.com/closest/